# In wso2 esb 4.8.0 salesforce connector not able to connect using enterperise api why?

Tags: salesforce, wso2, wso2-esb

I'm using wso2 esb 4.8.0 salesforce connector to connect salesforce but it is not even able to login using Enterprise API

https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/29.0

But when i use partner api it works fine.

https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/29.0

why i cannot connect through enterprise API ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a quick look at the [WSO2 Salesforce Connector Documentation](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB480/Salesforce+Connector) and the associated Zip file on [GitHub](https://github.com/wso2/esb-connectors/tree/master/distribution/salesforce).

The connector appears to be built around the Partner API. This makes sense, as the Partner API is generic and can be used with any Salesforce Org (assuming API access is enabled). Looking in the contents of the zip file there are xml files that align with the available Parther API methods.

[image: XML files for Partner API methods.]

The Enterprise WSDL in contrast is specific to the Org that generated it. This isn't suitable for a generic API wrapper as it contains objects that may only existing in one Salesforce Org.

See also: [Using the Partner WSDL](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_CSH.htm#sforce_api_partner.htm)

Comment: thank you. i too had a look at the connector i think for enterprise i should create my own connector .